# approximating probability mass function from a large data

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am learning elementary probability; especially I am interested in learning how to find probability mass functions and density functions from data.

I think I perfectly understand the theory: For example, let's take $X$ as a random variable which takes values $1$ to $10$ with frequencies $4,4,5,5,6,10,3,3,4,6$. I know how to calculate the relative frequency from this information, i.e. here $n=50$ data size. Now the approximate will be to perform this experiment sufficient amount of time, and then the relative frequencies converge to probabilities, and we have the distribution approximately.

Now, let's say I have data for, let's say, the last five years, 2021 to 2016, where each day I have seen a number between $0$ to $50$. Trials are independent. Based on this data, can I calculate $P[X=49]$ in $2022$ on a specific day? Thank you very much for helping me find out the PMF of such data.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Your variable  $X$ only takes values from $1$ to $10$, right?  So it can't be $49$.  Beyond that...well, real world data isn't like math problems.  You can't casually assume that data points are independent of each other (or independent from externals)  You need to have a model for whatever it is you are observing.

Comment: You have provided much too little structure for an answer. Are you assuming each day is an independent trial of some process that yields your number? Does the number depend on the date? If this is a real problem, not a hypothetical question made up for stackexchange then start with some data visualizaiion.

Comment: It's conceivable that you could do some useful modeling, but that depends a lot on what you're collecting data on. Such probabilities would be more reliable if you're collecting radioactive decay samples, say, than if you're collecting hospitalization numbers. You'll need domain expertise therefore. This is likely a question better directed toward data science: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Trials are independent. Does not depend on dates.

Comment: @lulu: I think the first paragraph may just have been an example.

Answer (score 2):

No. Time series data tends to be non-stationary (so, the distribution in 2022 might be different from 2016, etc).

Comment: OK, I have no idea about time-series data, but this straightforward NO makes me curious to ask since you said about distribution each year. Are you then saying that I can get probability distributions for each year? And they will be different, right?

Comment: Could you sketch an answer on how I will get distribution for each year?

Comment: If as you said the trials (days) are independent, and you have a discrete outcome, you just divide the number of times each outcome occurs by 365 and that will be your pmf. However, usually things measured on consecutive days are correlated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on independence, you can either use the histogram itself directly as a distribution in a non-parametric way, or else select a likely-looking family of discrete distributions and use something like [maximum-likelihood estimation (MLE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) to estimate the best parameter value or values. (For example, you might guess that your variable is Poisson distributed, and then use MLE to find the best value of the rate $\lambda$.) It helps if there are some *a priori* reasons to select that distribution family. Beyond that, it's hard to say anything more specific.

As I said in my comment, this question seems like it would be more suited for the folks at [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). They may be better able to help you there. You might prepare to share some of your actual data, as opposed to just describing it.